# Difference between sonar.sources and sonar.tests in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

What is the difference between sonar.sources and sonar.tests in while configuring sonarqube in Maven project configuration in jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

sonar.sources - comma-separated paths to dirs containing sources

sonar.tests - the same but for test sources

In the documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/ you can find information that its not compatible with Maven so probably it will look into default maven tests location

Comment: So Why do we seperate them (let's say., seperate path for source and seperate path for test source)? Can't we put them in a same parameter as sonar does the same for both the sources ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this -> https://community.sonarsource.com/t/impact-of-the-sonar-tests-parameter/11239/2
Here it says that tests are excluded from some rules that apply to src folder

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).